# Terraform functions inside conditions

Tags: interpolation, terraform

I've been struggling a bit trying to join 2 strings inside a condition. here is what I have

```
${var.log_expiration_days == "365" ? var.name : join("", [var.name, var.log_expiration_days])}
```

The error I get is this one

```
Error: Error loading modules: module alb: Error loading .terraform/modules/0daf126f48aa68f4100241c487117a28/main.tf: Error reading config for aws_lb[alb]: parse error at 4:77: expected expression but found "["
```

I haven't seen anybody run functions inside conditions, so I don't know if this is possible. However, on terraform's official documentation, it says functions are supported inside conditions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating the list using the [list](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#list-items-) interpolation:

```
${var.log_expiration_days == "365" ? var.name : join("", list(var.name, var.log_expiration_days))}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a list of variables and joining them you'd probably be better with using [`format`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#format-format-args-):

```
"${var.log_expiration_days == "365" ? var.name : format("%s%s", var.name, var.log_expiration_days)}"
```